# Which ML library to use on SHArC processsor?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, library

Is there a consensus on which ML libraries one could easily integrate (C/C++ API) on a somewhat rare CPU platform, like SHArC?

Library should be well maintained and relativelly easy to compile on a new platform (if platfrom is not supported out of the box). Does not have to support full set of ML functions, but a most used ones.

I've previously used Tensorflow Lite C on Arm - but it was easy to build for Arm because it's a supported platform. However, Tensorflow is big and hard to compile for unsupported platforms.